# Is calling the method "awakeFromNib()" necessary when setting cornerRadius in swift?

Tags: swift, uikit

I got this chunk of code from an online lesson teaching how to set round corners.

I comment out the `awakeFromNib(`) and the `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` method and run the simulator, the results are the same: the button still shows round corner without `awakeFromNib()`.

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 4.0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.setUpView()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        self.setUpView()
    }

    func setUpView() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
    }

}
```

I am wondering why should I use `awakeFromNib()` and the `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` when I already set the corner radius in the observer?

Comment: the observer is not invoked during initialisation ([source](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html)), it is possible you have set the radius explicitly (and unintentionally) in IB for the inspectable property, that is why you see the rounded corners.

Answer (score 3):

You ask:

> I am wondering why should I use `awakeFromNib()` and the `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` when I already set the corner radius in the observer?

The issue is what if you had your button added to the storyboard scene and didn’t have the `@IBInspectable` property set at all. Your layer’s corner radius would never be set to `3` (or `4`) because the observer is only called if subsequently changed after initialization. You need to make sure you don’t have a path of execution where the observer isn’t called (or at least update the layer’s corner radius based upon your property’s value). You need to configure your corner radius via one of those methods (or, as I’ll argue below, in `init`).

---

But what if you programmatically instantiate a button for some reason? In that scenario, neither `awakeFromNib` nor `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` will be called!

So, I would suggest doing it in `init`. This covers all scenarios:

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedButton: UIButton {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 3.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setUpView()
    }
}

private extension RoundedButton {
    func setUpView() {
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    }
}
```

I’m also not sure why you had one default in the `var` declaration, and another in `setUpView`, so I’d just have one to avoid ambiguity.

---

By the way, another approach is to use a computed property that gets it from the `layer`. This avoids any possible confusion (e.g. you programmatically change the `layer.cornerRadius` elsewhere, do you really want this `cornerRadius` property to return the old stored value rather than what the layer is really using)?

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedButton: UIButton {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get { return layer.cornerRadius }
        set { layer.cornerRadius = newValue }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setUpView()
    }
}

private extension RoundedButton {
    func setUpView() {
        cornerRadius = 4.0
    }
}
```

---